# MySql import backup - UTF8 problems

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, phpmyadmin, mysql

i have a .SQL mysql dump.
When i Import it, 'Ü' is displayed 'Ã¼' and so on.
The Same when i open it with Notepad++.

When i Change the charset in Notepad++ to UTF8 without Bom it is displayed correct.
Now it says "ansi as utf8".

But when i save it and Import it again, mysql generates 'Ã¼'.

The same when i try "convert to utf8 without bom" in Notepad++ ans save it .

Ive tried it with phpmyadmin and mysqldumper, i tried all "Input charset" options and so on - and i still dont get it. it doesnt work with any Settings.

I tried to fix in manually in the database and that worked - so the charset of mysql is ok i think.

Hope someone can help me out,

Regards

babacuek

Comment: So when you open the file explicitly as UTF-8, it's all good? Then the file is UTF-8 encoded, Notepad is just too daft by default to recognize it as such. How exactly are you importing the file then and what do your database settings look like?

Comment: hey,

i found a Workaround.
there is a php script which improves all wrong Tokens.
it works very vell.

here it is:
http://forum.mysqldumper.de/viewtopic.php?p=19187#19187

but thank u for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Just do that (sorry for delay)

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8 database
mysql> SOURCE utf8.dump
```